# Android - back from Contacts intent without selecting one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, back-button

In my android application I have a list of people (name and telephone number) and I let the user add a person to the app's database by importing one from their contacts list. Everything works fine, but a user could click the button to import a new person and then go back, so the Contacts intent will be closed without actually selecting a contact.

So I need to know where to put an if, or something else, in my code in order to see whether the user selected a contact or not.

```
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();

            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the name from the DISPLAY_NAME column
            String name =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ontactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // update database
            dbManager.addPerson(name, number, true);
        }
    }

}
```

So how can I check if the user actually selected a contact or went back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I need to know where to put an if, or something else, in my code in order to see whether the user selected a contact or not.

You already have the code for this: `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)`. If the user presses BACK, you will not get `RESULT_OK`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an startActivityForResult which will return you back to the same activity once your

```
Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts")
```

jobs gets over that is the user has selected a contact.

And in order to get the name , number or any other details of the contact selected you do it in your onActivityResult callback like follows :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if(reqCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            String cNumber = null;
            String cName = null;

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                String hasPhone = null;
                String contactId = null;

                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    try {
                        hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                        contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception Message : " + e.getMessage());
                        DisplayMessage.error("Sorry can't access contacts. Check permissions settings.", this);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (hasPhone != null && hasPhone.equals("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query
                                (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        if (phones != null) {
                            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex
                                        (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("[-() ]", "");
                                cNumber = phoneNumber;
                            }
                            phones.close();
                        }

                        cName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Contact name is:" + cName);
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
    }
}
```